# confused on my allotted static ip addresses and hope to get clarity

Tags: networking, ip, windows-server-2012-r2

I was given this for my dedicated server: xxx.xxx.232.80/28

From what I gather, my ip range is xxx.xxx.232.80 - 95 (or 94?)

I'm not sure since I really don't understand what a broadcast ip does for me. I vaguely understand what it does, but does it apply to Windows servers? Can .95 be used without any issues?

I couldn't get the computer on the internet unless I used a default gateway of xxx.xxx..232.81 which left my next ip .82 for my server. What happened to the .80 ip address? Is it still usable? I am on the internet so I hope I have it right.

Is my range truly 80-95?

I've done this before but when the server wouldn't reach the internet without me using the .81 ip address for the default gateway, that confused me.

Help a lost soul please and help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range goes from x.x.232.80 up to x.x.232.95 - this is a range of 16 addresses.

However, you lose three of these.  The first address is the network address and the last being the broadcast address.  The network address needs to be reserved for routing to work, and the broadcast address is needed for.. broadcasts - where something needs to go to all devices on the network (various discovery protocols do this).

And then you lose another one because you need a way off the network.  So there needs to be gateway to which everything is sent that is not destined for your network.  This is the default route, and in your case is x.x.232.81 and will be the address of a router that knows how to get to the internet.

So your useable range is .82-.94.

Comment: A lot more to the point than mine :)

Comment: great answer can you elaborate how you come up with the default gateway? I had an issue coming up with this.

Comment: It is difficult to determine, I determined it from your description.  Normally an ISP will set to to the first or last usable in the range, but they should always just tell you.  It is manually assigned.

Comment: ty for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have been given 16 IP addresses. However only 14 of them are usable. The Network Address for your subnet would be xxx.xxx.232.80 which identifies the network. The last address xxx.xxx.232.95 is used as your Broadcast Address. For broadcast traffic.

So any address xxx.xxx.232.81 ~ xxx.xxx.232.94 are valid addresses for use in your network. Well it seems xxx.xxx.232.81 is your Default Gateway so 82 ~ 94 sadly. You can use these if you are more curious on the technicalities:

Subnet Cheat Sheet:
http://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html

Network Address Definition: 
http://compnetworking.about.com/od/basicnetworkingconcepts/g/bldef_address.htm

Understanding Broadcast Traffic:
http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos13.2/topics/concept/broadcast-qfx-series-understanding.html